# Porting word2vec to RISC-V.. potential proxy kernel issue?

Tags: porting, riscv

We are trying to port word2vec to RISC-V.  Towards this end, we have compiled word2vec with a cross compiler and are trying to run it on Spike.

The cross compiler compiles the standard RISC-V benchmarks and they run without failure on Spike, but when we use the same setup for word2vec, it fails with "bad syscall #179!". We tried two different versions, both fail around the same place a minute or two into the run while executing these instructions. After going through the loop several 100k times, we see C1, C2 printed an then the crash. We are thinking this is more of a spike/pk issue than a word2vec issue.

Has anyone had similar experiences when porting code to RISC-V?  Any ideas on how we might track down whether it's the proxy kernel?

A related question is about getting gdb working with Spike.. will post that separately.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The riscv-pk does not support all possible syscalls. You'll need to track down which syscall it is and whether you can implement it in riscv-pk or if you need to move to running it on a different kernel. For example, riscv-pk does not support any threading-related syscalls as multithreaded kernel support is an explicitly riscv-pk non-goal.

I would also be wary of using riscv-pk in general. It's a very simple, thin kernel which is great for running newlib user applications in the beginning, but it lacks rigorous testing and validation efforts against it, so running applications that stress virtual memory systems, rely on lots of syscalls (iotcl and friends), or are expecting more glibc-like environments may prove problematic.